# How to set a future "start date" when using Stripe Checkout Session?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, checkout

How can I set `billing_cycle_anchor` or `current_period_start` with Stripe Checkout Sessions? I tried several ways, but it isn't working.

The alternative I found is, just creating the subscription separately, but I don't know how to enable promotional codes or how to redirect that subscription to a checkout page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [trial_end inside subscription_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end) to anchor your billing cycle, when creating a Subscription via Checkout

Comment: Thanks @orakaro. But the issue is, this is not the first payment, we are just allowing user to change their subscription package but it'll apply from a future date. So the `trial` functionality wouldn't work.